# Implement react-native render calendar week view

Tags: react-native

How to render week view dates like this for react-native:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you've seen [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/998) issue on Github relating to react-native-calendars and week views but I'm looking to do the same and from one of the comments stumbled onto the [react-native-week-view](https://github.com/hoangnm/react-native-week-view) package. There may be ways to customise its look a bit to make it look more like what you want above.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the react-native-calendars component. It offers views similar to the ones you are looking for https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Comment: @QuangPhungVan found a solution?